# What I need for the callback parameter for returnCharData function?

Tags: node.js, api, callback, poloniex, zenbot

N need some help here using this API.

I'm trying to get data from Poloniex API for NodeJS (npm Install)

I'm confuse with which parameter i have to pass here in the callback parameter, I'm new in nodeJS, so maybe im getting wrong what i need as a callback.

This method is used for the API to fetch data from the poloneix web, to calculate basic things, currently i need the information of the Pair BTC/USD, here is the property of the poloneix instance:

**`returnChartData(currencyA, currencyB, period, start, end, callback);`**

It is Declared as this in the `poloneix.js` file:

```
returnChartData: function(currencyA, currencyB, period, start, end, callback) {
            var parameters = {
                currencyPair: joinCurrencies(currencyA, currencyB),
        period: period,
        start: start,
        end: end
            };
```

What do I need to use in as a callback parameter for this Function?

```
var response = poloniex.returnChartData('BTC','LTC',300,1510570525,1510638955,**(¿here?)**)
        fs.appendFile('BTC_pair.json', response, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('there was an error: ', err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('BTC Pair Saved');
    });
```

I know it is Wrong, but i tried to use simple Fucntions, for example as a Timer to explore what i need to pass as a callback, and im getting this error while running executing my node file:

```
D:\Projects\NodeJS\ZenBot\ZenBot_v2\poloniex.js\lib\poloniex.js:79
                    callback(err, body);
                    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Request._callback (D:\Projects\NodeJS\ZenBot\ZenBot_v2\poloniex.js\lib\poloniex.js:79:7)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\Projects\NodeJS\ZenBot\ZenBot_v2\poloniex.js\node_modules\request\request.js:122:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\NodeJS\ZenBot\ZenBot_v2\poloniex.js\node_modules\request\request.js:888:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\NodeJS\ZenBot\ZenBot_v2\poloniex.js\node_modules\request\request.js:839:
12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

And in the `poloniex.js` File here in the constructor is where the error is comming:

```
_request: function(options, callback) {
            if (!('headers' in options)) {
                options.headers = {};
            }

            options.json = true;
            options.headers['User-Agent'] = Poloniex.USER_AGENT;
            options.strictSSL = Poloniex.STRICT_SSL;

            request(options, function(err, response, body) {
            // Empty response
            if (!err && (typeof body === 'undefined' || body === null)){
            err = 'Empty response';
            }

            callback(err, body);    <----- THIS LINE
        });
```

Do I need to declare any function? or something?

Comment: Done, i already solved this problem.
I use a wrapper callback funcion with an arrow Function to handle the error and the body dataSet.  Thnx Anyway. 

`var response = poloniex.returnChartData('USDT','BTC',300,date_1,date_2,(err,body)=>{
    if (err){
        console.log('ERROR', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(body);
    var str = JSON.stringify(body);
    fs.appendFile('usdtPairbtc.json', str, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('there was an error: ', err);
    return;
    }
        console.log('BTC Pair Saved');
    });
});`

Comment: Can you post this as the answer?